# ASP.NET MVC view cannot find asset

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc

I'm making an ASP.NET MVC website. Most of my views are under the View and their respective subfolders, and they are called Index. These views have no trouble fetching CSS and Images. These classes have `localhost:51227/example` like URLs.

However, when I add a view that is just another ActionResponse of a controller, the view cannot find any of my assets (images, css etc.). These views have `localhost:51227/example/action`.

What am I doing wrong with my routing?
Sample code:

```
public ActionResult Day()
    {
        ClientViewModel cvm = new ClientViewModel();
        cvm.Page = Page.TIMESHEET;
        return View(cvm);
    }
```

This is my Controller ActionResult.

[image: This is my folder structure]

Comment: Look at the generated HTML and check the locations that are being requested for the asset files through the developer tools of your browser. You probably print their URI wrong, causing them to be searched in `/example/action/style.css`.

Comment: And don't pity-upvote non-repro questions, please.

Comment: It'll help a lot if you show the view code and point out the line with the asset it can't find.

Answer (score 0):

The thing was that my inner URL's didn't start with a / so I wasn't looking from root.
Stupid question, sorry.